# chef client version upgrade and issues

Tags: chef-infra

We are planing to upgrade from chef 11 to chef 13 and in the due process testing our cookbooks. I am seeing below NoMethoderror for the following primary attribute. Everything works fine with chef 11 client.

upgraded Chef client version is 13.7.16

Error #

### NoMethodError

```
undefined method `www_test_server' for      #<Chef::Node::VividMash:0x0000000004a4eeb8>


  1>> default.www_test_server.packages = {
  2:    'test-apr'             => '1.4.8-3.el7',
  3:    'test-apache'    => '2.4.25'
  4:  }
```

Answer (score 1):

We removed the method-style access for node attributes in Chef 13. You'll have to use `node['www_test_server']['package']` or similar.